# Assembly Language -Addition of two signed numbers

Tags: assembly, tasm

Dear Stackoverflow community

**Question :** Given two signed numbers x = 01111110 (base 2) and y = 00001000 (base 2) .Explain why x + y operation will result into wrong results?

**My attempt :** (Understanding) From my research about sign number magnitude the only way x + y will be wrong will be if the answer overflows into the sign.

Please can anyone help me, I have researched and read about sign magnitude, one`s complement and two`s complement ,but still find it very confusing.

Thank you very much for taking the time and patience to see my question.

Comment: if you add two positive numbers should the result be positive or negative?  When you add these two positive numbers what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your signed integers are 8 bit wide, it's exactly as you said: it's overflowing in the sign bit, which (in 2's complement) results in wraparound.

```
01111110 +
00001000 =
10000110
```

As you can see, summing the two positive values (126 and 8, they both have the sign bit not set) resulted in a negative value (it has the sign bit set; in 2's complement, it's -122), which is obviously wrong.